# How do I pass installation dir from the installer to a custom action?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've been trying to achieve that for the last 2hrs. Can anyone help me out please? I'm trying to pass the installation directory to the custom action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accessing `Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"]` from the custom action?